# How to install Software Center on Kali Linux:

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

> E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
>    2 down vote

I'm trying to add this to repositories. **NOTE:** Editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` and adding these two lines:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/ /kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/ /wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Then in the terminal I run this command:

```
$ apt-get update
```

Then try:

```
$ apt-get install software-center
```

again I get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Add these to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Hope you noticed the extra `space` & '`/`' & the missing name in your sources list.

Comment: Hi,added these lines in sources.list                                                   root@kali:~# apt-get install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate

Comment: `apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install software-center`
Try: `apt-cache search software-center` to confirm the package exists

Answer (score 0):

install snap-store this page contain the steps to do that https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-kali then run this command `sudo snap install snap-store`

snap store is the default store in ubuntu and you will find all the apps that you want to install in ubuntu to kali